# How to Load Only .html page in WebView and All www Page load in Safari in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

i am newbie in iOS Development I load my HTML Data Into WebView But Some time it Contain only href link as .html link and some time website link like as `www.google.co.in` so i want to load only html data in to Webview and any website are load in to Safari for that i write a code like as

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
NSString *link = [[request URL] relativeString];
if ([link isEqualToString:@"module1learningobjectives.html"])
{
    return NO;
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
    return YES;
}
return YES;
}
```

then it load .html file in web view but site are open in safari and Webview both i want only site was open in safari please give me solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog("URL is %@, and has an extension of %@", request.URL, [request.URL pathExtension]);

    if ([[request.URL pathExtension] isEqualToString:@".html"])

        return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

Is this what you are asking?

If you want it to use Safari for non files and your own WebView for files, then try this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if ( ! ([request.URL isFileURL]) ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: How about some details?  What is request.url?  Does it end in ".html"?

Comment: @it is not load html file in web view.

Comment: now i write a code edit in my question when i click on website url then it open in safari and web view but i want it to open only in safari and in my new code my html page working fine.only website is open in both web view and safari i want open only in safari not web view please give me solution for it.

Comment: glad we figured it out.

Comment: here mine one question is if i want to play mp3 file on href link that contain .mp3 file it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your code to below code.

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        NSString *strLink=request.URL.absoluteString;
        if([strLink rangeOfString:@".html"].location!=NSNotFound)
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[request URL]];
            return NO;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Above code check if the link which is going to open has .html extension or not? and it works accordingly.

One more thing in your question you haven't mentioned that the href are link of local pages or external links.

Comment: .html href link is local page

Comment: then i suggest search for http:// protocol. So if link start with http:// then open safari else load in web view.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
 NSURL *url = request.URL;
    NSString * temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];
    if ([temp rangeOfString:@"www"].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        // show alert view for go to safari
        // i.e
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
    else
    {
        // your regular html page pushed
    }

}
```

Comment: This is fragile.  A local URL like mywwwserverfile.html would trigger the if statement.

Comment: Yes you are right.
Then you must be set some prefix world with herf link in app pages
safari <a href="SafariLink_www.google.com">
simple <a href="mywwwserverfile.html">

and change if condition  if ([temp rangeOfString:@"SafariLink_"].location == 0)