# Detect if the URL is different than my website in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an Objective-c app which opens my website on loading of the app.

Most of the links on my website points to different websites/URL.

I am trying to update my objective-C code where If the URL is different than my website opens the URL in safari browser instead of opening in my APP.

Is this even possible?

Here is my code

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Load the url into the webview
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com/"];
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Have you looked at the methods of `UIWebViewDelegate`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28040261/how-to-load-only-html-page-in-webview-and-all-www-page-load-in-safari-in-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` and specifically:

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)wv shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)type {
    if (![request.url.host isEqualToString:@"mywebsite.com"]) {
        [UIApplication.sharedApplication openURL:request.absoluteURL];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

And in swift

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType navType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if request.url?.host != "mywebsite.com" {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(request.absoluteURL)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C, not Swift.

Comment: So it is, just so used to swift, will add obj-c in too.

Comment: 1. `URLRequest` does not have a `host` property. 2. You should first check that the navigation type is a click on a link.

Comment: You missed a `!` in the Objective-C code. And why access the properties using method syntax instead of property syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You need implement the delegate of UIWebView and use:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

     if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
         NSString *url = request.URL.host;

         if([url rangeOfString:@"http://mywebsite.com"].location == NSNotFound) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
            return NO;
         }
         return YES;
      }

      return YES;

}
```

Comment: Instead of looking for a substring in the complete URL, my not look at just the `host` portion of the URL?

Comment: And you need to return `NO` after calling `openURL`. And replace `true` with `YES` (this is Objective-C).